# Control height only with padding

Tags: css, html-lists

I have font-size:14px, line-height:14px, padding top and bottom 7px. The total should be 28px.

This is right in a div, it makes 28px height. But the same in a ul li a, makes 30px. Can someone explain me why? where does this 2px come from?

(I need a exact height in a ul. I think I need to control it with the padding in the ul li a, as I want to make it all clickable)

Here is the example to play and check:
http://jsfiddle.net/nyv4x9jv/

```
#menu {
    padding:7px 14px;
    font-family: 'verdana', sans-serif;
    font-size:14px; line-height:14px;
    margin:0;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color:red;

}

#menu2 ul li a {
    padding:7px 15px;
    font-size:14px; line-height:14px;
    font-family: 'verdana', sans-serif;
    list-style-type:none;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin:0;
    background-color:red;
}

#menu2, ul, li, a  {
    margin:0; padding:0; border:0;
}


<div id="menu"> menu </div>

    <br><br>

    <div id="menu2">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#"> menu</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference because `div` is a block element and `a` is an inline element

Like said before you shouldn't apply line-height on the `a` field but on a upper level (just remove a from your CSS)

```
#menu2 ul li{
    padding:7px 15px;
    font-size:14px; line-height:14px;
    font-family: 'verdana', sans-serif;
    list-style-type:none;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin:0;
    background-color:red;
}
```

For more information about line-height properties, you can check

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height

Comment: I am not sure if I understand? This means that you cannot add top or bottom padding to an inline element only left and right
a es un inline element, ul o li are block elements. Is that correct?

Comment: ul,li and ol are block level element, you can add padding on any element as it is not restricted to block or inline, the problem here is only on `line-height` property that is incompatible with the `a` tag

Comment: Perhaps the easiest is to make ul li a { display:inline-block }. This way I can apply an exact height and all the zone is clickable

Answer (score 1):

Using `box-sizing:border-box` will allow you to set a fixed height on the anchor link that will include padding and borders.

Then it's just a matter of making sure the padding + line-height equals the total height you have set.

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#menu2 ul {
  font-family: 'verdana', sans-serif;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: red;
}
#menu2,
ul,
li,
a {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}
#menu2 ul li a {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 14px;
  padding: 7px;
  height: 28px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  background: #f09d09;
}
#menu2 ul li a:hover {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu2">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#"> menu</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try applying the padding settings to the **ul** element itself, not to the **a** element.

```
#menu2 ul{
 padding:7px 15px;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mqbazaoj/

Comment: This solves the problem with the exact height but If I do not give a padding to the 'a', only the leters will be clickable and not the hole button

Comment: Just put the <a> tag outside the li: <a href="#"><li> menu</li></a>

Comment: @RadulescuIulia **Actually you can't**...that's invalid HTML.